# SOLR - QT Export handler Field Aliasing

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj

Does not export handler support field aliasing.

For example, `fl=name:display_name` => name will be the alias for the field `display_name` (stored in SOLR)

Comment: what solr version are you using ?

Comment: Hi  i am using Solr 6.2.1